# wpf datagrid : create a DatagridNumericColumn in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a requirement that I want to make a datagridcolumn which only accepts numeric values(integer) ,when the user enter something other than numbers handle the textbox .
I tried a lot of webpages ,Iam tired of these ,I greately appreciate anybody have the helping mind.

Comment: You can create your own class derived from `DataGridColumn` and preform the numeric validation there ...

Comment: @Omribitan if you have any examples will you post the link it will be a great help for me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on @nit suggestion, you can create your own class derived from `DataGridTextColumn` like this:

```
public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(System.Windows.FrameworkElement editingElement, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;

        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(e.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Show some kind of error message if you want

            // Set handled to true
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the [PrepareCellForEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.preparecellforedit.aspx) method you register the `OnPreviewTextInput` method to the editing `TextBox` [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event, where you validate for numeric values.

In xaml, you simply use it:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NonNumericProperty}"/>
            <local:DataGridNumericColumn Binding="{Binding NumericProperty}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Use `TryParse` instead, this helps to restrict input values to integer numbers only.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This class help to create data grid cell which only support interger numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
    {
        protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
        {
            TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;

            if (edit != null) edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;

            return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
        }

        private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            int value;

            if (!int.TryParse(e.Text, out value))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a better solution avoiding raising exception. Just add the Paste feature from @Yoav.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to show any validation errors and just want to block any non-numeral value then you can create the `DataGridTemplateColumn` and in `CellEditingTemplate` use the `TextBox`.

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumericProperty}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" Text="{Binding Path=NumericProperty}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and in `PreviewTextInput` of the TextBox set `e.Handled = true` if value is other than integer:

```
       private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(e.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you ,But Actually I can't use DataGridTemplateColumn in my requirment

Answer (score 3):

I got here looking for a solution to the same problem: constraining the input into cells on a `DataGrid` to be numeric. But the accepted answer did not work for me.  The following did:

1. For the `DataGrid` add an event handler for `PreparingForCellEdit`.
2. In that event handler, cast the `EditingElement` to a `TextBox` and add an event handler for `PreviewTextInput` to the `TextBox`.
3. In the `PreviewTextInput` event handler set `e.Handled` to true, if the input should not be allowed.

The above steps work if the user clicks the cell to edit. However, if the cell is not in edit mode, the `PreparingForCellEdit` event will not be called. To perform validation in that case:

1. Add an event handler to the `DataGrid` for `PreviewTextInput`.
2. In that event handler, safely cast `e.OriginalSource` to a `DataGridCell` (exiting, if it is not a `DataGridCell`), check the `DataGridCell's` `IsEditing` property, and if the cell is not editing set `e.Handled` to true.

The effect of the above is that the user will have to click into the cell in order to edit its contents and, as such, the `PreparingForCellEdit` / `PreviewTextInput` combination above will be invoked for all changes to the cell's contents.

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend @Omribitan's answer, Here is the solution with a data `Paste` guard added:

```
public class NumericTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += Edit_PreviewTextInput;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(edit, OnPaste);
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        if (!IsDataValid(data)) e.CancelCommand();
    }

    private void Edit_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsDataValid(e.Text);
    }

    bool IsDataValid(object data)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(data);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For whatever it's worth, here's how I solved it. This solution allows you to specify a variety of options when validating input, allows string formatting to be used (e.g. '$15.00' in the data grid) and more.

The null value and string formatting provided by the `Binding` class itself do not suffice as neither act correctly when the cell is editable so this class covers it. What this does is it uses another class that I've been using for a long time already: `TextBoxInputBehavior`, it has been an invaluable asset for me and it originally came from [WPF – TextBox Input Behavior](https://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/wpf-textbox-input-behavior/) blog post albeit the version here seems much older (but well tested). So what I did I just transferred this existing functionality I already had on my TextBoxes to the my custom column and thus I have the same behaviour in both. Isn't that neat?

Here's the code of the custom column:

```
public class DataGridNumberColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    private TextBoxInputBehavior _behavior;

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

        // A clever workaround the StringFormat issue with the Binding set to the 'Binding' property. If you use StringFormat it
        // will only work in edit mode if you changed the value, otherwise it will retain formatting when you enter editing.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat))
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(element, TextBlock.TextProperty);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, FrameworkElement.TagProperty, Binding);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(element,
                TextBlock.TextProperty,
                new Binding
                {
                    Source = element,
                    Path = new PropertyPath("Tag"),
                    StringFormat = StringFormat
                });
        }

        return element;
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        if (!(editingElement is TextBox textBox))
            return null;

        var originalText = textBox.Text;

        _behavior = new TextBoxInputBehavior
        {
            IsNumeric = true,
            EmptyValue = EmptyValue,
            IsInteger = IsInteger
        };

        _behavior.Attach(textBox);

        textBox.Focus();

        if (editingEventArgs is TextCompositionEventArgs compositionArgs) // User has activated editing by already typing something
        {
            if (compositionArgs.Text == "\b") // Backspace, it should 'clear' the cell
            {
                textBox.Text = EmptyValue;
                textBox.SelectAll();
                return originalText;
            }

            if (_behavior.ValidateText(compositionArgs.Text))
            {
                textBox.Text = compositionArgs.Text;
                textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
                return originalText;
            }
        }

        if (!(editingEventArgs is MouseButtonEventArgs) || !PlaceCaretOnTextBox(textBox, Mouse.GetPosition(textBox)))
            textBox.SelectAll();

        return originalText;
    }

    private static bool PlaceCaretOnTextBox(TextBox textBox, Point position)
    {
        int characterIndexFromPoint = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(position, false);
        if (characterIndexFromPoint < 0)
            return false;
        textBox.Select(characterIndexFromPoint, 0);
        return true;
    }

    protected override void CancelCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, object uneditedValue)
    {
        UnwireTextBox();
        base.CancelCellEdit(editingElement, uneditedValue);
    }

    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement)
    {
        UnwireTextBox();
        return base.CommitCellEdit(editingElement);
    }

    private void UnwireTextBox() => _behavior.Detach();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(EmptyValue),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(DataGridNumberColumn));

    public string EmptyValue
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EmptyValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(EmptyValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsIntegerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsInteger),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridNumberColumn));

    public bool IsInteger
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsIntegerProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsIntegerProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StringFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(StringFormat),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(DataGridNumberColumn));

    public string StringFormat
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(StringFormatProperty);
        set => SetValue(StringFormatProperty, value);
    }
}
```

What I did is I peeked into the source code of `DataGridTextColumn` and handled the TextBox creation in *almost* the same way plus I attached the custom behaviour to the TextBox.

Here's the code of the behavior I attached (this is a behavior you can use on any TextBox):

```
public class TextBoxInputBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    #region DependencyProperties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegularExpressionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(RegularExpression), 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputBehavior), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(".*"));

    public string RegularExpression
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInteger)
                return @"^[0-9\-]+$";
            if (IsNumeric)
                return @"^[0-9.\-]+$";
            return (string)GetValue(RegularExpressionProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(RegularExpressionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MaxLength), 
        typeof(int), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(int.MinValue));

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(EmptyValue), 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputBehavior));

    public string EmptyValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EmptyValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmptyValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNumericProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsNumeric), 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputBehavior));

    public bool IsNumeric
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsNumericProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsNumericProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsIntegerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsInteger),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TextBoxInputBehavior));

    public bool IsInteger
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsIntegerProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                SetValue(IsNumericProperty, true);
            SetValue(IsIntegerProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowSpaceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(AllowSpace),
        typeof (bool),
        typeof (TextBoxInputBehavior));

    public bool AllowSpace
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(AllowSpaceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowSpaceProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += PreviewTextInputHandler;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += PreviewKeyDownHandler;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (AssociatedObject == null)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= PreviewTextInputHandler;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= PreviewKeyDownHandler;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
    }

    private void PreviewTextInputHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string text;
        if (AssociatedObject.Text.Length < AssociatedObject.CaretIndex)
            text = AssociatedObject.Text;
        else
            text = TreatSelectedText(out var remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection)
                ? remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection.Insert(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, e.Text)
                : AssociatedObject.Text.Insert(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex, e.Text);
        e.Handled = !ValidateText(text);
    }

    private void PreviewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            e.Handled = !AllowSpace;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmptyValue))
            return;

        string text = null;

        // Handle the Backspace key
        if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if (!TreatSelectedText(out text))
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart > 0)
                    text = AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
            }
        }
        // Handle the Delete key
        else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            // If text was selected, delete it
            if (!TreatSelectedText(out text) && AssociatedObject.Text.Length > AssociatedObject.SelectionStart)
            {
                // Otherwise delete next symbol
                text = AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, 1);
            }
        }

        if (text == string.Empty)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Text = EmptyValue;
            if (e.Key == Key.Back)
                AssociatedObject.SelectionStart++;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            var text = Convert.ToString(e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

            if (!ValidateText(text))
                e.CancelCommand();
        }
        else
            e.CancelCommand();
    }

    public bool ValidateText(string text)
    {
        return new Regex(RegularExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(text) && (MaxLength == int.MinValue || text.Length <= MaxLength);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle text selection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if the character was successfully removed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    private bool TreatSelectedText(out string text)
    {
        text = null;
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionLength <= 0)
            return false;

        var length = AssociatedObject.Text.Length;
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart >= length)
            return true;

        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart + AssociatedObject.SelectionLength >= length)
            AssociatedObject.SelectionLength = length - AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;

        text = AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, AssociatedObject.SelectionLength);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All the good credit for above Behaviour class goes to blindmeis, I merely tweaked it over time. After checking his Blog I see he has a newer version of it so you may check it out. I was very happy to find out I could use his behaviour on DataGrid as well!

This solution worked really well, you can edit the cell properly via mouse/keyboard, paste the contents properly, use any binding source update triggers, use any string formatting etc. - it just works.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
    <local:DataGridNumberColumn Header="Nullable Int Currency" IsInteger="True" Binding="{Binding IntegerNullable, TargetNullValue=''}" StringFormat="{}{0:C}" />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I went on from Omris approach
however i wanted to be able to delete the cell value after it has input in case they wanted to clear it

The way i did this was overriding the CommitCellEdit method and making the string null instead of blank. Im also using decimal? in my case

```
public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(System.Windows.FrameworkElement editingElement, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    
    {
        TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;

        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(System.Windows.FrameworkElement editingElement)
    {
        TextBox tb = editingElement as TextBox;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            tb.Text = null;
        
        return base.CommitCellEdit(editingElement);
    }
    void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToDecimal(e.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Show some kind of error message if you want

            // Set handled to true
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class extends the functionality of the earlier answers without becoming too complex as some of the later answers.

The main additions are:

- **TextBox_Loaded** to handle when the user starts typing directly over the cell instead of first entering edit mode
- **TextBox_LostFocus** to clean up the user's input. Takes care of leading 0's, trailing 0's after a decimal, etc.

The rest is pretty similar to previous answers except this checks if the numeric input is valid with Regex (allows negative numbers and decimals).

```
internal class CustomDataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var textBox = editingElement as TextBox;
        textBox.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, OnPaste);
        textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
        textBox.Loaded += TextBox_Loaded; // Add Loaded event handler to handle initial text
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.Loaded -= TextBox_Loaded; // Remove the event handler after it's executed once
        if (!IsValidNumericInput(textBox.Text))
        {
            textBox.Text = string.Empty; // Clear the text if it's not valid initially
        }
    }

    private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var proposedText = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
        if (!IsValidNumericInput(proposedText))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        if (!IsValidNumericInput(data.ToString()))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var text = textBox.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            textBox.Text = null;
            return;
        }

        if (decimal.TryParse(text, out decimal value))
        {
            textBox.Text = value.ToString("G29"); // Removes trailing zeros for a decimal
        }
    }

    private static bool IsValidNumericInput(string input)
    {
        const string numericPattern = @"^-?[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$";
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, numericPattern);
    }
  }
}
```