# Rectangle inside DataGrid, bind width value of rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to bind rectangle width property to a variable so with each added record to Data Grid the width of rectangle is different (chart style). I cannot even access this rectangle with `x:Name`.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Data}" Header="Data"  ></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pamaina}" Header="Pamaina"></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TyrimoVieta}" Header="Tyrimo vieta"></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Koncentracija}" Header="Koncentacija"></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rect">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="assTR">
               <Rectangle Width="{Binding ilgis}" Height="10" Fill="Green" />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

C#

```
List<DatagridItems> datagridItems = new List<DatagridItems>();
```

```
public class DatagridItems
{
   public string Data { get; set; }
   public string Pamaina { get; set; }
   public string TyrimoVieta { get; set; }
   public string Koncentracija { get; set; }
}

public List<DatagridItems> LoadCollectionData(string data, string pamaina, string tyrimovieta, string koncentracija)
{
   Datagrid_1.Items.Refresh(); //du refresh kad atsinaujintu kolekcija
   datagridItems.Add(new DatagridItems()
   {
      Data = data,
      Pamaina = pamaina,
      TyrimoVieta = tyrimovieta,
      Koncentracija = koncentracija,
   });
   Datagrid_1.Items.Refresh();

   return datagridItems;
}
```

Call to populate Data Grid

```
Datagrid_1.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData(datosFormatas, row["pamaina"].ToString(), tyrimoVieta_isFunkcijos, koncentracija);
```

I do not actually know if this will even do what I want. Below is the picture what im trying to achieve. I want value in "Koncentracija" to set width of green rectangle. Can this even be done? I managed to draw static width rectangle only.

Any help is appreciated. [Image of what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrtl0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want value in "Koncentracija" to set width of green rectangle. Can this even be done?

Yes it can be done.

Basically you want to bind a `string` type variable with a variable that is gonna represent the `width` of your rectangle. How?

Usually width is represented in numeric values ;)

So the simplest solution - you need to change the datatype of Koncentracija property to be `int` or `decimal` as @thatguy pointed out. But to keep things simple without using converters - you have to provide a mechanism to notify your view that property has changed.

The simplest way to do that is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and invoke the propertychanged event in the setter with the name of the property like so:

```
public class DataGridViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Pamaina { get; set; }
    public string TyrimoVieta { get; set; }

    private int koncentracija;
    public int Koncentracija
    {
        get { return koncentracija; }
        set
        {
            koncentracija = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Koncentracija));
        }
    }
}
```

I made a simple view to represent adding an element to DataGrid which changes the width of a rectangle by clicking a button. Here is the View code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="44,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Koncentracija}" Height="47" Margin="350,91,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Name="AddItemBtn" Content="AddToDataGrid" Margin="63,281,615.6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="53" FontSize="16" Click="AddItemBtn_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Now in the code behind your view (in my example "MainWindow.xaml.cs") there's a simple logic which you can adjust to your problem. Here I increment the Koncentracija value by 30, but ofc you can do that by getting the data from your desired object.

The code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataGridViewItem dataItem = new DataGridViewItem();
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person { Name = "Mark", Age = 12 }, new Person { Name = "Chris", Age = 22 } };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = people;
        DataContext = dataItem;
    }

    private void AddItemBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Tom", Age = 27 });
        dataItem.Koncentracija += 30;
        MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Here's a picture how it looks https://ibb.co/B4FCD6S
Hope it helps :)

*Edit: I recommend you to get familiar with MVVM pattern when creating WPF apps as it will help you a lot. There is a tutorial on this here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/index.htm

Comment: Thank you for detailed information. I ended up creating Width decimal inside my class for sole reason cause Koncentracija value was just too small to use in graph. Width = Koncentracija * 4. Have to look deeper into this MVVM pattern. cheers. [link](https://ibb.co/k2PBVFw)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netcore-3.1). You can put whatever you want inside of the `DataTemplate`.

This works:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Width">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="10" Fill="Blue" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`MainWindowVM.cs`

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainWindowVM : ObservableObject
    {
        private List<Item> _Items;
        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _Items; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Items)
                {
                    _Items = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item() {Name = "one", Width = 30.5 },
                new Item() { Name = "two", Width = 10.2 }
            };

        }
    }

    public class Item : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Name)
                {
                    _Name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private double _Width;
        public double Width
        {
            get { return _Width; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Width)
                {
                    _Width = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Datagrid with two columns. Second column has variable width rectangles]

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the `Koncentracija` property should be of type `double` and not `string`, but for that you would need to create a custom data column that provides support for numeric types and also validation to prevent invalid values, an attached beahvior or a conversion between types. You can find solutions to that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374471/wpf-datagrid-create-a-datagridnumericcolumn-in-wpf).

This would also allow you to simply bind the `Koncentracija` property to the `Width` of the `Rectangle` and it would work in your example. You could align the bar graph left with `HorizontalAlignment`.

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Koncentracija}" Height="10" Fill="Green" />
```

If you want to leave your code as it is, you could create a one-way converter for `Koncentracija`.

```
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      double.TryParse((string)value, out var result);
      return result;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

You would then create an instance of this converter for the `DataGrid` and bind the `Width` property to `Koncentracija` with the converter that automatically converts the `string` to `double`.

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:StringToDoubleConverter x:Key="StringToDoubleConverter"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Data}" Header="Data"  ></DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pamaina}" Header="Pamaina"></DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TyrimoVieta}" Header="Tyrimo vieta"></DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Koncentracija}" Header="Koncentacija"></DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rect">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel x:Name="assTR">
                  <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Koncentracija, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}" Height="10" Fill="Green" />
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As a general note, you should [implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) in your view model, otherwise changes to the properties at runtime will not be reflected in the user interface.